# Export image as Scalable Vector Graphic

Tags: export, grease-pencil, 2d

Hello,
Does anyone know if there is a way to export grease pencil drawing as pdf or
some other non pixel format?

Answer (score 3):

In blender render,

Goto>render settings

Tick>Freestyle

Then Tick>Freestyle SVG Export

Go back to>output
Choose a file to place your rendered work

Then hit>Render

Your SVG is ready at the specified output location

Additionally,
To prevent some object from rendering as SVG,
On the material tab, just click on Transparency

Comment: This only works in below 2.8 as the addon has not been made for 2.8

Comment: unfortunate, im using 2.8

Comment: @Gor It doesn't say that in the question. Please post concise questions with all the relevant information, to prevent others spending their time creating inapplicable answers.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a better way to do this:

- Simply select your grease pencil object in object mode
- Go to *File > Export > Grease Pencil as SVG* or *Grease Pencil as PDF*